# Line break problem in merging two dictionary objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have spent some time to look for an answer and have implemented many of the solution but they don't work. Basically, I have 2 dictionary objects in javascript and they are as followed when I console.log:

```
obj1 = {"\n  key1\n  ":["\n   a\n   ","\n    b\n "], "\n  key2\n":["\n  f\n  ","\n   e\n"], "\n   key3\n    ":["\n  fda\n", "\n    das\n"]}

obj2 = {"key2":["h","k","z"], "key3":["zzz","bbb"}
```

I want to merge the 2 objects into this:

```
obj3 = {"key1":["a","b"], "key2":["f","e","h", "k","z"], "key3":["fda", "das","zzz","bbb"]}
```

I have tried to use:

```
obj3= Object.assign({},obj1, obj2);
```

but the result is:

```
obj3 = {"\n  key1\n  ":["\n   a\n   ","\n    b\n "], "\n  key2\n":["\n  f\n  ","\n   e\n"], "\n   key3\n    ":["\n  fda\n", "\n    das\n"], "key2":["h","k","z"], "key3":["zzz","bbb"]}
```

Clearly the keys don't match because of those line breaks. I have tried to write a loop to remove the line breaks but it didn't work:

```
          function linebreak(obj) {
            for (var key in obj) {
              obj[key].toString().replace(/\n/g, "");
            }
          }
          linebreak(obj1)
```

Comment: Where are you getting these objects? I'd fix it at the source rather than trying to fix it after the fact...

Comment: @HereticMonkey From Wonderland ..?

Comment: @Teemu Maybe from Outer White Space?

Comment: It's a long way to get to these objects. Yes they were from Wonderland... I would rather fix the problem here than going back all the way :( . Please help!!

Comment: This kind of problems tend to cumulate. If you now fix this particular client-side use case only, other cases using the same data, or part of it, will need a fix too.

Comment: for now I need a solution for this one as soon as possible but later I will try to go back and fix it from the source. Please!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trim all keys and values in the malformed object and concatenate arrays with matching keys:

```js
const obj1 = {"\n  key1\n  ":["\n   a\n   ","\n    b\n "], "\n  key2\n":["\n  f\n  ","\n   e\n"], "\n   key3\n    ":["\n  fda\n", "\n    das\n"]}
const obj2 = {"key2":["h","k","z"], "key3":["zzz","bbb"]}

const result = Object.keys(obj1)
  .reduce((acc, key) => ({
    ...acc,
    [key.trim()]: obj1[key]
      .map(val => val.trim())
      .concat(obj2[key.trim()] || [])
  }), {});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: could you help me a bit further because there's a problem with the code design. It works perfectly with keys having more than one value (as all keys in my examples). However, if I throw in a key with only one value into obj1 ("\n key4\n  ":["\n value4 \n"]), I run into the error: " object.map() is not a function". I tried fixing it like this:

Array.prototype.slice.call(obj1[key]).map(val => val.trim())

However, this fix ends up tokenizing the single value of that key in order to turn it into an array

"key4": [" "," ", "v","a","l","u","e","4"]

I'll really appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 0):

The function `trim()` could help here:

```js
var str = "\n  key1\n  ";
var trimmedStr = str.trim();
console.log(str);
console.log(str.trim());
```

Basically, `trim()` removes all leading/trailing whitespaces and new lines from a string. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

**Edit:** In your original attempt, you are only removing new line characters; there will still be leading/trailing spaces. I'm talking about this line:

```
obj[key].toString().replace(/\n/g, ""); //should also include \s+ for spaces
```

Comment: The problem here is, that the keys of an object are immutable + `replace` doesn't replace in-place. Trimming itself would be a great solution when used correctly for the case.

Comment: Right. I need to replace the /n in-place. But I have a solution now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Test Cases

```
obj1 = { 
"\n  key1\n  ": ["\n   a\n   ", "\n    b\n "],
"\n  key2\n": ["\n  f\n  ", "\n   e\n"],
"\n   key3\n    ": ["\n  fda\n", "\n    das\n"] }

obj2 = {"key2":["h","k","z"], "key3":["zzz","bbb"]}

=>  key1: (2) ["a", "b"]
    key2: (5) ["f", "e", "h", "k", "z"]
    key3: (4) ["fda", "das", "zzz", "bbb"]
```

Hope it helps.

```
result = {}
for (var obj in obj1) {
    let key = obj.toString().match(/key[0-99]/)[0];
    let values = obj1[obj].map((post) => post.toString().match(/\w+/)[0]);
    if (!result.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        result[key] = [... values];
    }
    else {
        result[key].push(... values);
    }
}

for (var obj in obj2) {
    let key = obj.toString().match(/key[0-99]/)[0];
    let values = obj2[obj].map((post) => post.toString().match(/\w+/)[0]);
    if (!result.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        result[key] = [... values];
    }
    else {
        result[key].push(... values);
    }
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. I ran into a "Cannot read property *0* of null" error. But I now got a solution from below :)